# How to make a robot immovable in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to fix a robot (to be specific, pr2) to a specific location in gazebo. It is going to use its arm to touch and press some other objects in the environment, but its body should not be moved by the counter force. Resetting its location frequently may be a possible solution, but I am afraid that its arm and the objects in the environment may overlap in space and bounce away.

So I want to know if there is a way to disable movement of the robot in gazebo. Thanks.

Best,
Nan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37550/how-to-make-a-robot-immovable-in-gazebo/) by [Nan Jiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2653/nan-jiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't want the robot to move at all, I believe that in your urdf adding the entry  and create a fixed joint between world and your robot will do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [dearl](https://answers.ros.org/users/2762/dearl/) with karma: 96 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sapan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27831/sapan/) on 2018-07-21**:
I am trying to fix the robot

world
    base_link

but it doesn't work in sdf

**Comment by [Alice_ly](https://answers.ros.org/users/68815/alice_ly/) on 2021-08-12**:
Does that work in sdf file?